# mongoose: myModel.find always return subdocument

Tags: find, mongoose

```
  var myschema  = new Schema({
      name: {type:String, default:'fullname'},
      subdoc: {
          day1: {type:Array, default:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
          day2: {type:Array, default:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
      }
  });
  var mymodel = Mongoose.model('mytest',myschema);
  //mongoose 3.5.6: find
  mymodel.find({},{'name'}, function(err,docs){
      logger.info("---> " + docs);
  });
```

results:

```
---> { _id: 512da190ba48050f2e000001, **subdoc: {}**, name: 'fullname' }
```

Only `name` field is requested to be returned, but this function always returns `subdoc: {}`. Can someone explain this?

use mongodb shell, it looks fine

```
db.mytests.find({},{"name":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("512da190ba48050f2e000001"), "name" : "fullname" }
```

Then I change the model to:

```
var myschema  = new Schema({
          name: {type:String, default:'fullname'},
          subdoc: [
              day1: {type:Array, default:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
              day2: {type:Array, default:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
          ] // **note: not {} here**
      })
```

use the same mongoose api find, the result is just what I expected:

```
--->{ _id: 512da46fffebd24b30000002, name: 'fullname' }
```

My questions is: Why field 'subdoc' is returned with the former schema?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), it appears as if you are a little bit off.

Example:

> // name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields, executing immediately
>   MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends', function (err, docs) { })

With that, I would do something like this:

> myModel.find( {}, 'name', callback);

**Edit**

To address your comments: In mongodb console, the proper way to format it would be {'name':1, 'friend':1}.  Using:

> db.collection.find({}, {'name friend'})

will throw an error.  To do this properly, you would do:

> db.collection.find({}, {'name':1, 'friend':1})

However, if you prefer this way of field selection, mongoose does allow you to do that as well.

> myModel.find({}, {'name':1, 'friend': 1}, callback);

See: [API Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

Comment: Thanks for response, it's ok to use {'name friend '}.  when I use mongodb shell, this problem would not come. so i'm curious that why this happen in mongoose?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you.  You asked how to return just the name field using mongoose.  I explained the proper way to do that according to the docs.  You then ask, why subdocument gets returned.  Using the latest Mongoose, and using your code of myModel.find({},{'name'},callback);  I got an error.  What is your question that I didn't answer?  What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think we're talking about the same thing. 
My point is when I use find, the result like this: {id:xxxxx,name:xxxxx,subdoc:{}}, but I didn't request 'subdoc' at all. 
use then same commands on mongodb shell, it works fine, the result is just what I wanted:{id:xxxx,name:xxxx}. 
Then I modify this  model(subdoc field) to: 'subdoc: [day1:{xxx},day2:{xxxxx}]'.
(note: the origin is: subdoc:{...}, not subdoc: [...]) 
it works fine on both mongoose and mongodb shell.  
So I want to know why this happen, why field 'subdoc' is returned?

Comment: mongodb version: 2.2.3; mongoose version: 3.5.6